# What is the meaning of new { } (without [])?

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I'm doing a kinda-like research project on NUnit for class, and our teacher wrote this test:

```
[Test]
    public void ObjectLiteralIsAnObject ()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual (true, new { } is Object);
    }
```

I know the meaning of new[]{}, it creates an array of the best assignable type given the values you insert between {}. But what does new { } do? Is it just the same, or is there a small difference?

Thank you so much in advance, and sorry if it's a silly question!

Comment: This creates a new [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types)

Comment: The best way to answer these kinds of questions is to run `var x = new { };` in the debugger and look at what `x` contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new { }
```

is used to create anonymous object, in another words an unnamed object.

It is often used in LINQ queries, for example:

```
var query =
    from c in db.Customers
    select new
    {
        c.CustomerId,
        c.CustomerName
    };
```

This creates `IQueryable` of anonymous type with two properties: `CustomerId` and `CustomerName`

Comment: It does very much have a 'concrete' type. Just not a named one.